Media3 exoplayer for both tv and mobile - Looses focus on the control buttons in TV
I am building a video player library with jetpack compose and jetpack media3 exoplayer. I have to make it work both on phones and TV. Is there any official sample of media3 exoplayer and leanback integrated together to refer? I gone through many docs, i didnt find any useful resources for TV. I had added a simple video player. But the issue is that the control buttons loosing focus sometimes. When the remotes buttons are pressed nothing happens some times.I cant use custom controls. I have to use the defalult control from media3 only.This is my implementation.
@OptIn(UnstableApi::class)
@Composable
fun VideoPlayer(
    videoUrl: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    title: String = "Bugs Bunny",
    description: String = "",
    artistName: String = "",
    artworkUrl: String = "",
    playWhenReady: Boolean = true,
    seekBackSeconds: Int = 5,
    seekForwardSeconds: Int = 10,
    isInListItem: Boolean = false,
    resizeMode: Int = VideoResizeKeys.RESIZE_MODE_FIT,
    lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current,
    onFullScreenToggle: (Boolean) -> Unit = {},
    onIsPlayingChanged: (Boolean) -> Unit = {},
    onPlayerError: (Int) -> Unit = {},
    onKeyEvent: (NativeKeyEvent) -> Unit = {}
) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }

    val mediaMetadata = remember {
        MediaMetadata.Builder()
            .setArtworkUri(Uri.parse(artworkUrl))
            .setTitle(title)
            .setDisplayTitle(title)
            .setDescription(description)
            .setAlbumArtist(artistName)
            .build()
    }

    val mediaItem = remember {
        mutableStateOf(
            MediaItem.Builder()
                .setUri(videoUrl)
                .setMediaMetadata(mediaMetadata)
                .build()
        )
    }

    val exoPlayerListener = remember {
        object : Player.Listener {
            override fun onIsPlayingChanged(isPlaying: Boolean) {
                onIsPlayingChanged(isPlaying)
                Log.d(LogTag, "onIsPlayingChanged: $isPlaying")
            }

            override fun onPlayerError(error: PlaybackException) {
                onPlayerError(error.errorCode)
                val cause = error.cause
                Log.e(LogTag, "PlaybackException Occurred: ${error.message} caused by $cause")
            }

            override fun onMetadata(metadata: Metadata) {
                super.onMetadata(metadata)
                Log.d(LogTag, "onMetadata: ${metadata}")
            }

            override fun onMediaMetadataChanged(mediaMetadata: MediaMetadata) {
                super.onMediaMetadataChanged(mediaMetadata)
                Log.d(LogTag, "onMediaMetadataChanged: ${mediaMetadata}")
            }


        }

    }

    val exoPlayer = remember {
        ExoPlayer.Builder(context)
            .setSeekBackIncrementMs(seekBackSeconds * 1000L)
            .setSeekForwardIncrementMs(seekForwardSeconds * 1000L)
            .build().apply {
                this.setMediaItem(mediaItem.value)
                this.prepare()
                this.playWhenReady = playWhenReady
                this.addListener(exoPlayerListener)
            }
    }

    val playerView = remember {
        PlayerView(context)
    }

    DisposableEffect(lifecycleOwner) {
        val observer = LifecycleEventObserver { _, event ->
            if (event == Lifecycle.Event.ON_START) {
                if (exoPlayer.isPlaying.not()) {
                    exoPlayer.play()
                }
            } else if (event == Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP) {
                exoPlayer.pause()
            } else if (event == Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY) {
                exoPlayer.removeListener(exoPlayerListener)
                exoPlayer.release()
                Log.i(LogTag, "ON_DESTROY release player")
            }
        }
        lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.addObserver(observer)
        onDispose {
            lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.removeObserver(observer)
            Log.i(LogTag, "Dispose release lifecycle observer")
        }
    }


    val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
    var isControllerViible by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }


    Box(
        modifier = modifier.onNotVisible {
            Log.i(LogTag, "onNotVisible on screen called")
            if (isInListItem) {
                exoPlayer.stop()
                exoPlayer.removeListener(exoPlayerListener)
                exoPlayer.release()
            }
        }
    ) {
        AndroidView(
            factory = {
                playerView.also {
                    it.requestFocus()
                }
            },
            update = {
                it.player = exoPlayer
                it.setShowBuffering(PlayerView.SHOW_BUFFERING_WHEN_PLAYING)
                it.setControllerAnimationEnabled(true)
                it.setShowFastForwardButton(true)
                it.setShowRewindButton(true)
                it.setShowNextButton(false)
                it.setShowPreviousButton(false)
                it.showController()
                it.setFullscreenButtonClickListener(onFullScreenToggle)
                it.setResizeMode(resizeMode.asAspectRatioFrameLayoutResizeMode())
                it.setAspectRatioListener { targetAspectRatio, naturalAspectRatio, aspectRatioMismatch ->
                    Log.i(
                        LogTag,
                        "onAspectRatioUpdated: $targetAspectRatio, $naturalAspectRatio, $aspectRatioMismatch"
                    )
                }
                it.setControllerVisibilityListener(PlayerView.ControllerVisibilityListener {
                    isControllerViible = it == View.VISIBLE
                })
                it.controllerAutoShow = true


                if (DeviceType.isTv(context)) {
                    val playPauseButton =
                        it.findViewById<ImageButton>(androidx.media3.ui.R.id.exo_play_pause)
                    val rewindButton =
                        it.findViewById<Button>(androidx.media3.ui.R.id.exo_rew_with_amount)
                    val forwardButton =
                        it.findViewById<Button>(androidx.media3.ui.R.id.exo_ffwd_with_amount)
                    val settingsButton =
                        it.findViewById<ImageButton>(androidx.media3.ui.R.id.exo_settings)

                    listOf(
                        playPauseButton,
                        rewindButton,
                        forwardButton,
                        settingsButton
                    ).setFocusedBackground()
                }


            },
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .focusable(
                    enabled = true,
                    interactionSource = interactionSource
                )
                .onFocusChanged {
                    Log.i(LogTag, "onFocusChanged: ${it.hasFocus}")
                }
                .onKeyEvent {
                    if (isControllerViible)
                        playerView.dispatchKeyEvent(it.nativeKeyEvent)
                    else {
                        playerView.showController()
                        playerView.dispatchKeyEvent(it.nativeKeyEvent)
                    }
                }
                .focusRequester(focusRequester),
        )

    }
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        focusRequester.requestFocus()
    }
}

I have to integrate leanback library please refer any official docs with exoplayer and media3 leanback.
Thanks in advance
